# Spatial autocorrelation in the limit of a uniform system

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Consider [Moran's I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran%27s_I), a spatial autocorrelation function defined by

$$
I(x) = \frac{N}{W} \frac{\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{N} w_{ij} (x_i-\langle x\rangle )(x_j-\langle x\rangle ) }{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} (x_i-\langle x\rangle )^2 },
$$
where $w_{ij} \geq 0$ are weights, $W = \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{N} w_{ij} $ is the sum of the weights and $\langle x\rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} x_i$ is the mean of $x=(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_N)$.

This quantity is undefined at $x = 0$, or more generally whenever $x_i = x_j$ for all $i, j$. Suppose we take the metric induced by the norm $|x| = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} |x_i|$. I'm interested in the limit 
$$\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0} I(x).$$

---

What I've tried:

Define $y = x - \langle x \rangle $, then define (functions for the nominator and denominator) 
$$
f(y) = \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{N} w_{ij} y_i y_j, \\
g(y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} y_i^2
$$

If $\forall i$ we have $|y_i| < \delta$, then 
$$
|f(y)| \leq \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{N} w_{ij} |y_i| |y_j| < W \delta^2, \\
|g(y)| \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} |y_i|^2 < N \delta^2
$$
From this we only obtain
$|I| < 1$, which is a trivial result.

---

Another idea was to use [l'Hopital's rule for multivariable functions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0363.pdf), for which the zero set for $f$ and $g$ would be $C = \{x| x_i = x_j \forall i,j \} = \{y=0\}$. Hence we can take tangent vector $v=(1,0,\ldots, 0)$, so $D_v f(y) = \partial_1 f(y)$ and $D_v g(y) = \partial_1 g(y)$. However, this also does not give the limit and upon reapplying the rule we get $\partial_1^2 f(y) = \partial_1^2 g(y) = 0$.

Comment: Is $\langle x \rangle$ the mean or the sum?

Comment: It's the mean, thanks for pointing out the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $I(tx)=I(x)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, so in order for $\lim_{x\to0}I(x)$ to exist we would need $I(x)$ to be constant, which is not the case for $N>2$.